Why coefficient of discharge is considered a constant?
Why is the discharge coefficient for a fixed geometry, say an orifice, considered a constant? Shouldnt it depend on the flow rate?
Coeffiecient_of_discharge = Actual_discharge/Theroretical_Discharge
For a given pressure difference across the orifice, we get an Actual_Discharge which would be different from the Theoretical_discharge, and so we get a value for the discharge coefficient.
But now if the pressure difference increases, won't it impact how the vena contract behaves, and won't the Actual_Discharge vary differently than the Theoretical discharge causing the value of the discharge coefficient to change?
I know the coefficient is not a constant with the Reynolds number, but does it change with the flow rate or the pressure difference across the orifice?

will it change with viscosity?

@solarmike  Yes, may be due to its effect of the Re?. But that is the question. Does Cd change or is it a constant.

A bit of research gives this which may help you: https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/orifice-plate-flow-meter
